# Change default dynamic web module version in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, tomcat7, apache-axis

I have a Dynamic Web Project in **Eclipse**. Using **tomcat 7** with **AXIS2**.
In project facets, i have already configured AXIS2 with the **Dynamic Web Module 2.2**(because AXIS2 doesn't work with **Web Module 3.0**).

But when i try to use WebService wizard (**New -> Web Service**) Eclipse try to create the Web Service with the Web Module 3.0, ignoring the Facets configuration of the origin project. The problem is, axis2 does not work with Web Module 3.0, so this process fails.

Is there any way to change the default version of the Web Module used by this wizard? Or maybe remove webModule 3.0 from the options?

I Looked in the server configuration, axis2 configuration, and Web Serves and didn't found nothing about changing this.

Thanks! Excuse my english... I left here the entire error message:

```
Unable to add the follwing facets to project jbws: Axis2 Web Services Core, Dynamic Web Module, Axis2 Web Services Extensions.
    org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: One or more constraints have not been satisfied.
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.modifyInternal(FacetedProject.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.mergeChangesInternal(FacetedProject.java:1181)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.access$2(FacetedProject.java:1117)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject$1.run(FacetedProject.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2345)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.modify(FacetedProject.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.consumption.ui.common.FacetOperationDelegate$1.run(FacetOperationDelegate.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
    Contains: Axis2 Web Services Core 1.1 requires Dynamic Web Module with version matching expression "2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5".
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, right-click your project, select `Properties`, select `Project Facets`. You will have all sorts of options, one of which is the `Dynamic Web Module` version.

Comment: Yes, i did that for the origin Web Project. It is marked with Web Module v 2.2. But, always when i try to use the wizard to make the WebService, it try to create it with WM 3.0 anyways, so it fails because Axis2, and do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to open your org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.prefs.xml file located in .settings folder and verify your dynamic web module version is set correctly.

Regards,
Ivo